# How can I destroy the chart in this script?

Tags: vue.js, components, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I cannot figure out how I can destroy my chart if it exists before re-rendering it? (e.g. after changing dates)

Here is my Vue component:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { Line } from "vue3-chart-v2";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Chart",
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    chartOptions: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions)
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: [
      {
        handler: "renderCharts",
      },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    renderCharts() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions)
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why would you wan to destroy it before rendering it? It doesn't exist then

Comment: Because I'm updating the chart when I'm picking new dates
Thus, if it exists, I would like to destroy it

Comment: Should happen automatically when you provide new data by the wrapper